# Identification: Star Trek Voyager - real civilization treated like Age of Empires (i.e. a real-time strategy game)

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, episode-identification

I'm pretty sure there was a Voyager episode where Tom Paris (and another officer) were playing a real-time strategy game (like Age of Empires) but then they found out they are controlling actual dueling civilizations.

Comment: If I remember right (no guarantees) Blink of an Eye (Season 6) has a bit of that feel at some moments, where they watch a species evolve rapidly, and can watch the consequences of their choices.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest that was a cool episode.

Comment: [Would you like to play a game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WarGames)?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I suspect you are getting Voyager confused with an episode of Stargate Atlantis.

The Season 3, Episode 15, [The Game](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/The_Game) had the same premise, with McKay and Sheppard finding and playing what they believe to be a computer game left behind by the Ancients. Only to discover that they are actually sending commands to two different countries and civilisations on an actual planet, causing conflict between them.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_Atlantis_(season_3)):

> Major Lorne's team discovers a planet that fits the description of
> what Sheppard and McKay mistook as a video game they found in the
> Atlantis database. It turns out that, through a series of Ancient
> satellites above planet M4D-058, the game has been controlling real
> people, the People of Geldar and Hallona, who now stand on the brink
> of war and destruction.

Comment: This is the one I was thinking of as well. I think the confusion may have been in part because the SG:Atlantis uniforms are the same sort of primary-colour and grey as starfleet uniforms.

Comment: Sounds like a bit of a rip off (or possibly an intentional homage) from *Ender's Game*...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Stargate has a lot of references to existing science fiction from clever allusions to outright parody.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman imho it sounds nothing like Enders Game…

Comment: Another thing that may have added to the confusion is that Robert Picardo was in SGA (though not in that particular episode).

Comment: @Moo "A person think he's playing a  simulated game of war, but he's actually sending commands to a real army fighting a real battle." Sounds similar enough to me.

Comment: @Arthur if you go broad enough, anything matches anything else.  In Voyagers case theres no purposeful intent to deceive the main character, no conflict between humanity and aliens, no Battle School, no “miracle leader”, no magic weapon, no psychic contact with another alien species…. For me there was much more of a likeness to stories about ancient Greek or Roman Gods manipulating humanity, including the visual aspects used.

Comment: @moo it’s basically the plot of the book.

Comment: @Preston then in turn Enders Game is ripping off ancient tales itself so…  I still disagree.

Comment: I would propose Star Treks "A Taste of Armageddon" is more of an inspiration if anything is.  And I'm not saying that.  But as I recall the Atlantis episode did force the antagonists to consider the real consequences of war if they kept it up.

Comment: @Moo You seem to be discussing based off of just this high-level description of the episode - it really is nothing like Enders Game. The characters in the show are playing what they believe to be a very detailed 'civ builder' game, where they each shape and guide an entire society down to things like common hairstyles. Both accuse each other of 'cheating' by advancing their civilisations' technology unnaturally. The war is a product of their 'gameplay' rivalry that they then realise is causing actual violence after they discover the planet, and they then work in-person to solve the conflict.

Comment: @Kayndarr I think you misunderstand which side of the argument Im on - I am very much arguing that this episode has nothing whatsoever to do with Enders Game.  You and I are in agreement.

Comment: @Moo Ah apologies, looks like I got a bit lost in that comment chain :)